# NullPointerException at OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

I'm getting a NullPointerException at the line:

```
mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

however I don't see any reason it should be occurring.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

LOGCAT:

```
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at com.project.new.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.onClick(ConfigFinalActivity.java:182)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14111)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
08-15 15:19:25.090: E/AndroidRuntime(24692):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

SOURCE:

```
project com.project.new.datasettings;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ConfigFinalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ConfigActivity";
    TelephonyManager tm;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    private Notification mNotification = null;
    private Button mXButton = null;
    private Button mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private Button mReadAgainButton = null;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int count;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;
    int i, g = 0, result = 0;
    String Result = "";
    public static ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
    XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;

    public static final Uri APN_TABLE_URI = Uri
            .parse("content://telephony/carriers");
    public static String Base_URL = "https://www.mysettings.com/";
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    UpdateActivity update;
    public static String status;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        update = new UpdateActivity();
        nameArr = update.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = update.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = update.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = update.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = update.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = update.getMmscProxyArr();
        portArr = update.getMmsPortArr();
        count = update.getCount();
        if (ApnArr.isEmpty() || mmscArr.isEmpty() || mmsportArr.isEmpty()
                || mmsproxyArr.isEmpty() || proxyArr.isEmpty()
                || portArr.isEmpty()) {
            tryagain();
        } else if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

            // Update APN table
            try {
                result = updateTable();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }// Settings updated with this atomic call
            catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (result != -1) {
                status = "success";

            } else {
                status = "failure";
            }

            if (status.equals("success")) {
                completeUpdate();
            } else if (status.equals("failure")) {
                tryagain();
                // showAlert(getString(R.string.unchanged_net10_dialog));
            }

        } else {// ICS and later versions

            // Reduce number of steps to 6
            TotalSteps = 6;
            setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
    //      String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.instructions_1);
    //      CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
            TextView assistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
    //      assistText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.assist_update_btn:

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {

            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;

            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
                //mReadAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                // mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);

                // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS
                // and
                // up is selected
                // Create ConfigActivity Intent
                // Intent i = new Intent(this,
                // NotificationActivityForMultiProf.class);
                // Invoke ConfigActivity Intent to start the assisted update
                // startActivity(i);
                // finish();

                // startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            }
        }  if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {

            // mAssistUpdateButton = (Button)
            // findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            // mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));

            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();// } else if (v == mReadAgainButton) {




            // go back to set of instructions if read again is selected
        //  mInstructionNumber = 2;

    //      setContentView(R.layout.screen5);
////            String one_text = String
////                    .format(getString(R.string.one), TotalSteps);
////            CharSequence styledText_one = Html.fromHtml(one_text);
//          TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_one);
//          one.setTextSize(18);
//          one.setText(styledText_one);
//          String two_text = String
//                  .format(getString(R.string.two), TotalSteps);
//          CharSequence styledText_two = Html.fromHtml(two_text);
//          TextView two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_two);
//          two.setTextSize(18);
//          two.setText(styledText_two);
//          String three_text = String.format(getString(R.string.three),
//                  TotalSteps);
//          CharSequence styledText_three = Html.fromHtml(three_text);
//          TextView three = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_three);
//          three.setTextSize(18);
//          three.setText(styledText_three);
    //      mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
        //  mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
    }



    /*
     * Insert a new APN entry into the system APN table Require an apn name, and
     * the apn address. More can be added. Return an id (_id) that is
     * automatically generated for the new apn entry.
     */
    public int InsertAPN() throws SecurityException {

        int id = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
            // values2 = values1;
            values2 = getValues();
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                Uri newRow = resolver.insert(APN_TABLE_URI, values2);
                // System.out.println("values in insertAPN" + values1);
                if (newRow != null) {
                    c = resolver.query(newRow, null, null, null, null);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Newly added APN:");
                    // TF Settings have been inserted
                    // Obtain the apn id
                    int idindex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    id = c.getShort(idindex);

                    Log.d(TAG, "New ID: " + id
                            + ": Inserting new APN succeeded!");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            if (c != null)
                c.close();
        }
        return id;

    }

    public ContentValues getValues() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("name", nameArr.get(i));
        values.put("apn", ApnArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsc", mmscArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsproxy", mmsproxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsport", mmsportArr.get(i));
        values.put("proxy", proxyArr.get(i));
        values.put("port", portArr.get(i));
        values.put("mcc", (getString(R.string.mcc)));
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo)));
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att)));
        }
        return values;
    }

    /*
     * Delete APN data where the indicated field has the values Entire table is
     * deleted if both field and value are null
     */
    private void DeleteAPNs(String field, String[] values)
            throws SecurityException {
        int c = 0;
        c = getContentResolver().delete(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null);
        if (c != 0) {
            String s = "APNs Deleted:\n";
            Log.d(TAG, s);

        }

    }

    /*
     * Return all column names stored in the string array
     */
    private String getAllColumnNames(String[] columnNames) {
        String s = "Column Names:\n";
        for (String t : columnNames) {
            s += t + ":\t";
        }
        return s + "\n";
    }

    /*
     * Copy all data associated with the 1st record Cursor c. Return a
     * ContentValues that contains all record data.
     */
    private ContentValues copyRecordFields(Cursor c) {
        if (c == null)
            return null;
        int row_cnt = c.getCount();
        Log.d(TAG, "Total # of records: " + row_cnt);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();//
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
            Log.d(TAG, getAllColumnNames(columnNames));
            String row = "";
            for (String columnIndex : columnNames) {
                int i = c.getColumnIndex(columnIndex);
                row += c.getString(i) + ":\t";
                // if (i>0)//Avoid copying the id field
                // id to be auto-generated upon record insertion
                values.put(columnIndex, c.getString(i));
            }
            row += "\n";
            Log.d(TAG, row);
            Log.d(TAG, "End Of Records");
        }
        return values;
    }

    // showAlert displays the text contained in message as an alert
    public void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        ConfigFinalActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        mErrorAlert = builder.create();
        mErrorAlert.show();
    }

    // showErrorAlert displays an alert with layout and a title
        private void showErrorAlert(int layoutRes, String title) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            // Get the layout inflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = ConfigFinalActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            builder.setTitle(title)
                    .setView(inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null))
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.assisted_button),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(
                                            Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
                                    try {
                                        showNotification();
                                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
            mErrorAlert = builder.create();
            mErrorAlert.show();
        }

    // showNotification starts the process of sending notifications to the bar
    // to assist the user in updating the data settings on ICS and later
    // versions of Android
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    void showNotification() throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {

        String field = getString(R.string.config_name_label);

        String value = Values.get("name").toString();
        int mId = 1;
        String title = "1 of " + TotalSteps + " (Update " + field + ":)";
        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(value);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivityForMultiProf.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(field, value);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotification = mBuilder.getNotification();
        mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mNotification);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mNotification != null) {
            outState.putString("NOTIFICATIONB", mNotification.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (mErrorAlert != null)
            mErrorAlert.dismiss();
    }

    private int updateTable() throws IOException, SAXException,
            ParserConfigurationException {
        int insertResult = -1;
        // returned value if table is not properly updated

        try {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            // Query the carrier table for the current data settings
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(APN_TABLE_URI, null,
                    "current=?", new String[] { "1" }, null);
            values = copyRecordFields(c);
            // Copy the NET10 settings into values

            // Replace T-Mo/ATT Data settings if there is no SIM or
            // NET10/T-Mo/ATT SIM is
            // present
            if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                            .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {

                // delete all APNs before adding new APNs
                DeleteAPNs("numeric=?",
                        new String[] { getString(R.string.numeric_tmo) });
                // Insert NET10 Data Settings into Carrier table

                insertResult = InsertAPN();

            } else if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                            .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
                // Delete all APNs before adding new APNs
                DeleteAPNs("numeric=?",
                        new String[] { getString(R.string.numeric_att) });
                // Insert NET10 Data Settings into Carrier table

                insertResult = InsertAPN();

    //      } else
                // non NET10/ non T-Mo SIM/non ATT SIM
        //      showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_net10_dialog));
            }   } catch (SecurityException e) {
        //  showErrorAlert(R.layout.assisted_settings,
        //          getString(R.string.assited_title));
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return insertResult;
    }

    private void completeUpdate() {
        // Displaying final layout after pre-ICS automatic settings update
        setContentView(R.layout.completion);
    //  TextView mCompleted = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.done_text1);
    //  String mDoneText = String.format(getString(R.string.done_text1));
    //  CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(mDoneText);

    //  mCompleted.setText(styledText);
        mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
        mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void tryagain() {
        // Displaying final layout after failure of pre-ICS automatic settings
        // update
        //setContentView(R.layout.tryagain);
        String tryAgainText = "";
        CharSequence styledTryAgainText;
//
//      tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text1),
//              TotalSteps);
//      styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
//      TextView tryAgain1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text1);
//      tryAgain1.setText(styledTryAgainText);
//
//      tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text2),
//              TotalSteps);
//      styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
//      TextView tryAgain2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text2);
//      tryAgain2.setText(styledTryAgainText);
//
//      tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text3),
//              TotalSteps);
//      styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
//      TextView tryAgain3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text3);
//      tryAgain3.setText(styledTryAgainText);

    }

    // This function return a cursor to the table holding the
    // the APN configurations (Carrier table)
    public Cursor getConfigTableCursor() {
        return getContentResolver()
                .query(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getnameArr() {

        return nameArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getApnArr() {

        return ApnArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMMSCArr() {

        return mmscArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMmscProxyArr() {

        return mmsproxyArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMmsPortArr() {

        return mmsportArr;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getProxyArr() {

        return proxyArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPortArr() {

        return portArr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just go to line 182 of your activity class file and see what object may be null there. Since you are just posting an excerpt of your activity class file (without package name, import statements) it's hard to tell which one is line 182

Comment: I update my source to include the package name and imports - line 182 is mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this); (I just have no idea why it is null)

Comment: Make sure that `assist_update_btn` is the `id` of a `Button` in `assist_instructions.xml`. And for future reference, it is usually better to not include imports and everything else that isn't relevant. Rather, tell us what line it is as you did here.

Answer (score 2):

You call:

```
mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
```

From the documentation:

> ```
> public View findViewById (int id)
> ```
>
> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that
>   was processed in onCreate(Bundle). Returns
>
> The view if found or null otherwise.

So, `assist_update_btn` does **not** exist in `R.id`.  Check spelling/location of `assist_update_btn`.

Comment: Also, in the future, please post the smallest amount of code possible.  There is a lot superfluous code there.

Answer (score 1):

As Nobu's comment says, it's a little difficult to determine the exact line responsible with a code excerpt and no line numbers, but I found these three lines in your code close to line 182 with the third line matching the line you asked about:

```
 mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
 //mReadAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
 mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I would expect a NullPointerException here if mAssistInstrButton was null, so I would suggest checking (either by adding logging or using a debugger) to make sure the `findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn)` method call is returning something other than null. Are you certain passing `R.id.assist_update_btn` to that method will a Button instance and not null?

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById` is apparently returning a `null` value. You could wrap it in an if condition to check for that case, or you could edit the `findViewById` function itself.

Hard to be more specific with the excerpt you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

The logcat directs to the fact that the view to which you are assigning a listener doesn't exist i-e; their is no view with ID `assist_update_btn` , thats why you are getting NullPointerException when you try to assign `clickListener` to a button that doesn't exist in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

As the others say: it could be that findViewById returns null because the view could not be found.

But it can also be a rare glitch in the build process, which also happened to me a few times during Android app development. Code portions that used to work all the time suddenly crash with NullPointerExceptions.

The build process can be a bit shaky sometimes and resources do not get correctly processed or updated. If you are sure that the view exists and the id is correct (if it used to work for you all the time before) then clean your workspace and build the app project new from scratch.

This can even happen sometimes with drawable and string resources, they can get switched and messed up.